# Javascript - Delete part of a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to delete part of the string after the 4th `\n`.

Now I have the array but I need to join it like the original string. Any help?

```js
let data = "My Name is John Travolta.\nHow are you my friend?\nShow me the gun\nWhat is your name?\nI DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE";

console.log(data);

// I want to hide -> I DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE


let cleanData = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, 4);

console.log(cleanData);
```

Comment: You want to join it? Have you looked at the `join` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the splitted array by `\n`

```js
let data = "My Name is John Travolta.\nHow are you my friend?\nShow me the gun\nWhat is your name?\nI DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE";

let cleanData = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/, 4).join('\n');

console.log(cleanData);
```

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the substring and lasIndexOf methods.

For example:

```js
let data = "My Name is John Travolta.\nHow are you my friend?\nShow me the gun\nWhat is your name?\nI DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE";
data = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf('\n'));
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not like regex. I think it is cryptic. I have implemented in both ways though.

```js
    const phrase = "My Name is John Travolta.\nHow are you my friend?\nShow me the gun\nWhat is your name?\nI DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE";

    const regex = /(.*)$/;
    const removedLastLine = phrase.replace(regex,'')
    
    console.log(removedLastLine)
    console.log(phrase.replace('I DONT WANT TO SHOW THIS MESSAGE', ''));
```